# Changing the search url according to language

Tags: custom-post-types, urls, plugin-polylang

I'm using Search and filter, Polylang and Custom post type UI plugins. I have a problem with the project's search in a specific language. The search form allow you to select category and location of the project. In default language all works fine so if I select the category "Design" and the location "Italy" it returns me the url

```
www.mysite.com/categories/design/?location=italy
```

In the italian page, for the same search, it returns me the same url instead of

```
www.mysite.com/it/categories/design-it/?location=italia
```

How can I fix this problem?